# xcode - Disable interaction with cell with scrolling enable

Tags: xcode, uitableview

From another view controller, I need to block the interaction of table view cells, but still allowing the scroll property.

I used:

```
table.userInteractionEnabled  = NO;
table.scrollEnabled = YES
```

but userInteractionEnabled disables all operations, including the scroll.

Is there any way to do that from table properties?

Answer (score 1):

From the attribute inspector

- Selection

  [image]

Programmatically :-

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None // In CellforRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: I have ask about properties of table not cell, because  I need to use table properties from another view and programatically. If I not found another solution, I try with cell how you said, although I think your solution not disable the cell, only sets to none the style when select the cell.

Comment: UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None is the Style of selection (color). "None"  means no style is applied when you touch the cell, but action still  work. I tried it, and do you?